# Three.js - How to preserve color information of input file

Tags: three.js, ply-file-format

How do you *preserve the color information* of a PLY file in Three.js?

I've the following colored point cloud `input_model.ply` which looks like this:

[image: input_model_ply]

I'm already aware of the following portion of code from https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_ply.html

```
// PLY file

var loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();

loader.load( 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/input_model.ply', function ( geometry ) {

    var material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { color: 0x0055ff, flatShading: true } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

    mesh.position.y = 0;
    mesh.position.z = - 1;
    mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 20;
    mesh.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.05 );

    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

    scene.add( mesh );

    } );
```

But when the scene is rendered I lose all my `input_model.ply` color information and the point cloud is displayed in a monochromatic way (and specifically in color: 0x0055ff)

How can I get this to work?

Comment: In your material options, try `( vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors )`.

Comment: Already tried that. Does not work.

Comment: What do you think you could do so someone would have sufficient information to help you?

Comment: I can edit the question posting the full code. Would this help? I tried to focus on the code block that is causing the problem. I can also edit the question clarifying what my PLY file looks like in terms of headers and stuff. I tried to do what is suggested in the question "three.js - ply files - why colorless?" but did not help.

Comment: Make sure you are using the current version of three.js. Provide a simple live example if possible, or if not, provide a link to the ply file... For a point cloud, try `MeshPointsMaterial` with vertex colors set.